# A problem concerning characterization entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $C$ and suppose $P$ is a polynomial in $z$,so that for some constant $M$ one has $$|f(z)|\leq M |P(z)|$$ for all $z\in C$.
Show that there is a constant $C$ so that $f(z)=CP(z)$ for all $z\in C$.

My solution: From the inequality presented above, we know that every zero of $P(z)$ is also $f(z)$'s. So $\dfrac {f(z)} {P(z)}$ is well defined and holomorphic in $C$ with absolute value smaller then or equal to M on the set $\left\{z|P(z)\neq  0\right\}$. But I when it comes to the domain$\left\{z|P(z)=0\right\}$,we can extend our function continuously. So that from the fact that the bounded entire function is constant,the desire result drops out.

Is my solution convincing or having some logic bugs?

Comment: How do you know you can extend the function continuously?

Comment: @mike The steps are valid. However you need to refine your supporting arguments. Like "we can extend our function continuously" is not correct. try to show that the points are removable singularities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can avoid division by relying on the fact below, which follows from series expansion:

> If $f$ is holomorphic on $U$ and $f(z_0)=0$, then $f(z)=(z-z_0)g(z)$ with $g$ holomorphic on $U$.

We now prove your result by induction on the degree of $P$.

- If the degree of $P$ is $0$, then $P$ is a constant and the result follows from Liouville's theorem.
- Otherwise, as you have noted, every zero of $P$ is a zero of $f$. Let $z_0$ be a zero of $P$. Then $P(z)=(z-z_0)Q(z)$ and $f(z)=(z-z_0)g(z)$ and so $|g(z)|\le M|Q(z)|$ for all $z\ne z_0$ and also for $z=z_0$ by continuity of $g$ and $Q$. By induction, $g(z)=CQ(z)$ and so $f(z)=CP(z)$.